# Proximity alert not working

Tags: android

I know there are many questions like this, but none of them seems to work for me, and it's getting a bit frustrating because I have no feedback of what is happening. Here's my code

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class InformMe extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static final long EXPIRATION = -1;
private static final String PROXIMITY_ALERT = "com.example.PROXIMITY_ALERT";

private LocationManager locationManager;
private AttractionNearReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_informme);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    View btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_set_inform);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    receiver = new AttractionNearReceiver();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float radius = Float.parseFloat(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_radius)).getText().toString());

    addProximityAlert(41.8723889, 12.48018, radius);

}

private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, EXPIRATION, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_ALERT); 
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
}
```

And the receiver

```
package com.example;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class AttractionNearReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    long[] vibratePatern = {0, 300, 200, 300, 200, 300};

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SeeAttractionOrComment.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                            .setTicker("near you")
                                            .setContentText("Added by")
                                            .setContentTitle("beach")
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beach) 
                                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                            .setSound(alarmSound)
                                            .setVibrate(vibratePatern);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

No errors, no exceptions, just nothing. I have tried on an emulator and on the real device, but the there's no notification comming.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding proximity alerts for the location (0,0).  That would be in the Atlantic Ocean.  Assuming you're not on a cruise ship, that probably isn't what you want.

Edit:  here's some working code I've used in the past to add an alarm.  Feel free to adapt it.

```
private int requestID = 0;

public void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, int radius, String category, Object data, ProximityListener listener) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_INTENT_NAME);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Request id parameter is not documented, but allows us to have multiple alerts outstanding so long as they are unique
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestID++, intent, 0);
    mAlerts.add(new AlertData(latitude, longitude, radius, category, data, listener, proximityIntent));
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, 
                                       -1, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration 
                                       proximityIntent);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_INTENT_NAME);  
    mContext.registerReceiver(proximityAlertReceiver, filter);

}
```

Comment: Ok, it's true, I modified that when trying on an emulator, but I'll change it, it makes confusion. But thanks for noticing. Anything else?

Comment: I added some code I've used in the past to do this, its been debuged using the mock location service.  Feel free to alter it to your needs

Comment: Ok, thank you, but can you tell me how is different from what I am doing?

Comment: I'm not setting the UPDATE_CURRENT flag in my pending intent.  I also was using a Service Context and not the application Context.  That sometimes matters-  generally you want to avoid using application context.  I'm assuming you put a breakpoint in the receiver and it was never going off, right?  And how were you testing it?

Comment: Yes, the flag was previously set to 0, than I changed it to UPDATE_CURRENT. And I have then practically moved all to code to onCreate of that activity, so when I'm creating an Intent I'm passing this for context. I have put the breakpoint in the receiver, and it never goes off. I have tried it on a real device, and on emulator - by setting the location on DDMS. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually getting a GPS lock (does the GPS signal symbol ever become solid, or does it continue to flash)?

Comment: It's not visible at all, both on the device and on emulator. I don't know if it should be visible on the emulator I have never tested it before, and on the device is surely turned on.

Comment: Then that's your problem-  no GPS lock, so proximity alarms won't go off.  Do a requestLocationUpdates rather than getLastKnownLocation.  Also, you may need to leave the area and come back, it might not fire if it starts within the radius.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it, I used requestLocationUpdates first, and now works both on the device and on the emulator! But I don't understand, why do I have to use it, I thought that I should just register pendingIntent for ProximityAlert? Why do I need to call this method? Isn't it just enough that I turn on the GPS, set the intent to be fired, and when in the radius, system service should fire the intent? If I don't use requestLocationUpdates, it doesn't work?

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html but I thought that requestLocationUpdates is needed because you need to register yourself for Location Listener? What should I do if I don't need to be informed when location changes, just need the proximity alert? How to use requestLocationUpdates in that case, and what to use for time and distance?

Comment: You still need to be registered, so that someone is using the GPS system and turning on the GPS radio.  If you don't care about the actual updates, ignore them by doing nothing in the update function.  You won't actually be draining more battery that way, its the readio which takes it up, not the small amount of processing power.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I must ask you one more thing, to see if I understood well, sorry for bothering you. So that means that even though you turn on the GPS in settings, it's not really turned on, unless there's an app registered as using it, probably for saving power reasons? That is why notification icon did not appear until I used requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: Yes.  The GPS radio takes a *lot* of battery power.  Its off unless needed.  That's why the NETWORK_PROVIDER exists-  to save power.  The GPS setting is more about whether apps are allowed to turn on the GPS radio, it doesn't actually turn it on.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you have enlightened me! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Gabe Sechan stated, you are pointing a place that you probably doesnt desire.

LocationManager.addProximityAlert needs latitude and longitude to properly work. Look at android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

`public void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)`

Note:
Set a proximity alert for the location given by the position (latitude, longitude) and the given radius.

You could use getLastKnowLocation to get your position through the desired provider and then call addProximityAlert with the values you got.

`public Location getLastKnownLocation (String provider)`

Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.

Like this:

`Location lastKnownLocationGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

`addProximityAlert(lastKnownLocationGPS.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocationGPS.getLongitude(), radius);`

Remember to verify for null return.

Comment: Thanks, but I have read the documentation, and explained above that coordinates were 0,0 temporary, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I can't comment on Gabe post, but I would like to add, that if you enter and leave the region very fast, you may not be noticed. Android documentation note: "Due to the approximate nature of position estimation, if the device passes through the given area briefly, it is possible that no Intent will be fired. Similarly, an Intent could be fired if the device passes very close to the given area but does not actually enter it." This may be a problem on production environment (real device), so stay aware of it..